# Basic bank program exiting before doing anything

Tags: c++

I've tried debugging and it appears to stop before the braces just after `int main`. Can someone please help we with a solution and explain why it is not working.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

enum Menusystem  // enum is a function used to convert the list of words below
                 // into numbers.
{
  ShowMenu,
  EnterName,
  Account,
  Deposit,
  Withdraw,
  Balance,
  Exit
} menu;

int main() {
  string customer;  // declaring variables and their data types for the menu
                    // options.
  string accounttype;
  string name;
  int credit;
  int debit;
  int currentbal;

  bool exit = false;  // declaring variable as boolean setting it to false so
                      // that when the loop gets to true it will break the loop.
  int option = 0;  // declares showmenu as a integer and sets value to 0 so that
                   // the menu will be displayed upon opening the program as in
                   // the code below the menu is displayed if option is equal to
                   // 0.

  while (!Exit)  // declares that if the exit button has not been pressed the
                 // application will stay open.
  {
    switch (menu)  // initiates a switch statement which will allow the program
                   // to cycle through menu options depending on the menu option
                   // they select.
    {
      case ShowMenu:
        cout << "[0] - Show menu\n"  // displays menu options to user.
             << "[1] - Enter Full Name\n"
             << "[2] - Enter Account Type\n"
             << "[3] - Deposit Funds\n"
             << "[4] - Withdraw Funds\n"
             << "[5] - Display Balance\n"
             << "[6] - Exit Program\n";

        cin >> option;
        if (option == 0)
          menu = ShowMenu;
        else if (option == 1)
          menu = EnterName;
        else if (option == 2)
          menu = Account;
        else if (option == 3)
          menu = Deposit;
        else if (option == 4)
          menu = Withdraw;
        else if (option == 5)
          menu = Balance;
        else if (option == 6)
          menu = Exit;
        else
          menu = ShowMenu;  // default case is to show the menu.
        break;

      case EnterName:
        cout << "Please enter your full name >\n";
        getline(cin, name);
        menu = ShowMenu;
        break;

      case Account:
        menu = ShowMenu;
        break;

      case Deposit:
        menu = ShowMenu;
        break;

      case Withdraw:
        menu = ShowMenu;
        break;

      case Balance:
        menu = ShowMenu;
        break;

      case Exit:
        menu = ShowMenu;
        break;

      default:
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How does it stop -- you need to be more specific

Comment: `while (!Exit)` this is checking the value of the enum of `Exit`, which is grater then zero, so the `while` cycle exits immediately. You wanted to use either lower case `exit` as a bool, or `while (menu != Exit)`

Comment: thanks for the response this is what worked i new it was probably down to a small error i had made and that i hadn't proof read my code thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
while (!Exit)
```

With

```
while (!exit)
```

Comment: thanks for the response this is what worked i new it was probably down to a small error i had made and that i hadn't proof read my code thanks again

Comment: @user3560533, then mark my solution as the answer to your question :-)

Answer (score 0):

This line is a `while (false)` loop

> while (!Exit)